# getting this error on SQL - Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "ROUND" at [4:1] for COUNT function

Tags: sql

```
SELECT usertype,
   CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route
   COUNT(SUM(Row) AS num_trips
   ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60), 2) AS duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY 
num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Missing comma after AS route, and after S num_trips. And more.

Comment: Count `(` and `)`, same number?

Answer (score 0):

Please, correct syntax as per below, where you missing ")" after "COUNT(SUM(Row)":

> SELECT usertype,    CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ",
> end_station_name) AS route    COUNT(SUM(Row)) AS num_trips
> ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60), 2) AS duration FROM
> `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`  GROUP BY
> start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype ORDER BY  num_trips
> DESC LIMIT 10